# Is $ M=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: |x|\leq 1\} $ a compact or connected set?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, connectedness

Let $$M=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: |x|\leq 1\}.$$

I know that this set is closed and limited, if I'm not wrong. But can someone tell me something about whether it is compact or connected.

Comment: This set is not limited. It is connected. It would probably be simplest to prove that it is  path connected.

Comment: Hint: Where is $y$ in the equation?

Comment: If $(x,y) \in M$ we have a restriction on $x$ (we know $|x| \le 1$) but do we have any restriction on $y$?  So far as I can tell $y$ can be anything we want.  Can we determine if $M$ is bounded or not when the $y$ value of any pair is utterly unrestricted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the set is a strip bounded by the lines $x=1$ and $x=-1$. Hence fails to be bounded, so not compact. Further, the set is path-connected, namely

for any $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ in the set,

$$t(x_1,y_1)+(1-t)(x_2,y_2)=(tx_1+(1-t)x_2, ty_1+(1-t)y_2).$$

Now, note that $|tx_1+(1-t)x_2|\leq t|x_1|+(1-t)|x_2|\leq 1 \qquad \forall t~\in (0,1).$

Since path-connected implies connected, the set happens to be connected.

Comment: Thanks for answer the question, i appreciated. :)

Comment: You are very welcome @JamesA.Agamez

Answer (score 1):

The set $M$ is unbounded, since it contains every point of the plane of the form $(0,y)$, with $y\in\Bbb R$. So, it is not compact. And it is connected since it is path-connected: if $p\in M$, then$$\begin{array}{rccc}\gamma\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&M\\&t&\mapsto&tp\end{array}$$is a path in $M$ going from $(0,0)$ to $p$.

Comment: Thanks for help me with the question. :)

Comment: I suggest that you mark one of the answers as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

The Heine Borel Theorem says a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.  This *looks* closed (but is it?) and although the for every $(x,y) \in M$ we have the $x$ term apparently bounded there is no restriction on the $y$ value so it doesn't look bounded.

Formally show it is not bounded we can use the definition of bounded.  There exists an $K\in \mathbb R$ so that for any two points $a,b$ in $M$ then $d(a,b) \le K.

That is not true.  For any $K$ we attempt pick to bound it we will have $(1,0)$ and $(0, K) \in M$ and $d((1,0)(0,K)) = \sqrt{1 + K^2} > K$ so we can't find any $K$ where all $a,b \in M$ would ahve $d(a,b) \le K$.

So $M$ is not bounded and therefore not closed and bounded and therefor not compact. (BTW... is we want to find an open cover with no subcover let $U_{w, z} = N_1((w,z))$, that is unit open balls.  That covers all of $\mathbb R^2$ so it covers all of $M$. Each ball has a finiter area so any finite group of them cover only a finite area and $M$ is infinite in area.)

.....

Connected.  It *looks* connected.  If $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)\in M$ then it seemes if we draw a straight line then any $(x_i, y_i)$ on the line will have $|x_i| \le \max(|x_1|, |x_0|) \le 1$ so $(x_i, y_i) \in M$.